# jquery mobile popup fixed at top not working?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Hi im using jquery mobile 1.2.0 and using popups. i need to show a popup in my jquery mobile page which contains a listview but when the popup is show i can scroll it down while for example the header is in fixed position. i tried

```
$("#pushNotificationExample").bind({
 popupafteropen: function(event, ui) {
  $("#pushNotificationExample").css({position:'fixed', top:0}); }
});
```

but no luck. is there another way to do this?

Comment: You want to show it under the header or above it? Your code shows that you want to fix it at the top of the window/screen.

Comment: I want to show it on top of the header But in a fixed position so that when im scrolling it does not scroll too.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? this will fix it to the top.let me know should you have any question.

Comment: It places it there but when i start scrolling it starts to move while the header which is fixed stays fixed. at the moment i solved it by not allowing scrolling while popup is shown

Answer (score 2):

The below will position the popup at the top and center of the page.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Jr9Va/)**

```
$('#popupMenu').on('popupafteropen', function () {
 var center = ($(document).width() - $('.ui-popup-container').width()) / 2;
 $('.ui-popup-container').css({
   top: 0,
     left: center
 });  
});
```

Comment: how to apply this property to all the popups in the HTML..? I am using JQuery mobile with Phonegap

Comment: @Mannii88 instead of id #popupid try .ui-popup I can't give a definite answer because I don't have access to pc right now.

Comment: thanks Omar! i was also looking fr answers and tried at a similar method, it worked:)

Comment: sry fr the late reply though..was busy with some business aspects of the app, which kept me occupied:) just nw had publishd the app in playstore..

Comment: @Mannii88 I'm glad it worked for you, good luck on the app :)